# Calculating Pressure Loss (K Value) of Pipe Bends at varying Angles

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, piping, bending

I am analyzing the total pressure loss of a run of pipe that has several pipe bends at varying angles (30, 60, 45, 90, etc. degrees). Reading through CRANE: Flow of Fluids Through Valves, Fittings, and Pipe, it seems that there are equations that calculate for 90 degree bends but none that factor in pipe bends at other angles.

Is there an equation to determine the pressure loss of non 90-degree pipe bends?

Answer (score 0):

So consult some of the many tomes that cover pipe losses in detail.

This comes from: https://www.accessengineeringlibrary.com/content/book/9780070471788/back-matter/appendix6

[image]